# ImportError: No module named pandas [pycharm] python 3.7

Tags: pandas, module, pycharm, named

I write the code like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import quandl

df = quandl.get('WIKI/GOOGL')
print(df.head())
```

and I have the error as below

C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\untitled1\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/Administrator/PycharmProjects/untitled1/regression.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Administrator/PycharmProjects/untitled1/regression.py", line 1, in 
    import pandas as pd
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'

Process finished with exit code 1

I tried to test many recommendations from the internet, but I cannot fix this error. Please help me! Thank you so much.

Comment: Which version of python you are using, is it bare python or Anaconda?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using bare python install pandas using pip "pip install pandas", If you are using anaconda, check your python interpreter from pycharm. Go to `File->Settings->Project Settings->Project Interpreter->Python Interpreters` Ensure to select correct version of python.exe e.g `C:\Program Files\Python37\python.exe` for bare python (For this you need to install pandas ) For anaconda you'll see `C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\python.exe`. select the correct interpreter and you are good to go